# Error de timeout al cargar datos url android

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en `Android Studio` (api min es 10). EN esta aplicación cargo los datos que obtengo a través de una url. Cuando el dispositivo en la que la pruebo es mayor de la api 10, lo realiza correctamente.Sin embargo cuando es la api 10 no se recibe nada. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

El código de la tarea en background es el siguiente:

```
private class DownloadJsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    private ArrayList<String> parseJsonCentrosFile(String jsonLibrosInformation)
            throws JSONException {

           //Parseo de los datos
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            return null;
        }
    }
    private ArrayList<String> downloadUrl(String myUrl) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = openHttpInputStream(myUrl);

            try {
                return parseJsonCentrosFile(streamToString(is));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {

            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    public String streamToString(InputStream stream) throws IOException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int length = 0;
        do {
            length = stream.read(buffer);
            if (length != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } while (length != -1);
        return baos.toString("UTF-8");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {

      //Código de onPostExecute

    }
}
```

Código obtención conexión:

```
 private InputStream openHttpInputStream(String myUrl)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ProtocolException {
    InputStream is;
    URL url = new URL(myUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    conn.connect();
    is = conn.getInputStream();
    return is;
}
```

El archivo que se accede por la url no lo descarga por lo que creo que el error es eso. ¿Cómo podría descargar el json y luego leerlo del archivo que me descarga?

El error del logCat es el siguiente:

```
04-14 18:36:53.281 793-807/
es.libros/AndroidRuntime:FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                         at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
                                                                         at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
                                                                         at es.user.bares_restaurantes.BarListFragment$DownloadJsonTask.streamToString(BarListFragment.java:703)
                                                                         at es.user.bares_restaurantes.BarListFragment$DownloadJsonTask.downloadUrl(BarListFragment.java:677)
                                                                         at es.user.bares_restaurantes.BarListFragment$DownloadJsonTask.doInBackground(BarListFragment.java:664)
                                                                         at es.bares_restaurantes.BarListFragment$DownloadJsonTask.doInBackground(BarListFragment.java:328)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208) 
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: agrega tu código, es importante agregues más información a tu pregunta! :)

Comment: El código no creo que sea el problema porque con otras apis me funciona. ¿Tendría que ver algo que los datos que se cargan a través de la url son muchos y que por eso se agote el tiempo?

Comment: Podría estar relacionado, usas las clases de Apache para conexión o HttpUrlConnection?. Podría ser tu conexión ya que como comentas son muchos datos, y según el dispositivo podría tardar más o menos procesarlos, si no termina a tiempo se produce el timeout. El código considero es importante para cualquier pregunta ya que en base a eso podríamos por ejemplo sugerir definir un timeout mayor y tal vez sea eso la solución.

Comment: Añadí el código de la conexión y de la tarea en background. Realizo la conexión mediante la clase HttpURLConnection.

Comment: Prueba primeramente definiendo un timeout, conn.setConnectTimeout(10000); //timeout 10 seconds y me comentas que sucede! ç

Comment: las pruebas en api 10, las haces en el emulador o en un dispositivo fisico?

Comment: Las hago en un emulador. El dispositivo es: 3.2 HVGA slider (ADP1) API 10

Answer (score 1):

#### Descartando el timeout en la conexión tenemos que El problema es un "**Unexpected end of Stream**", causado probablemente por caracteres acentuados.

Cambia tu método `streamToString()` usando `StringBuilder` :

```
public String streamToString(InputStream stream) {
    try {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuilder totalDatos = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            totalDatos.append(line);
        }
        return totalDatos.toString();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "UnsupportedEncodingException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

También puedes modificar tu método `openHttpInputStream()` para obtener el InputStream si la conexión fue exitosa, código 200 y así verificar por esa parte no hay problema.

```
private InputStream openHttpInputStream(String myUrl) {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {

        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.connect();
        int connCode= conn.getResponseCode();
        if (connCode== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            Log.e(TAG, "SE REALIZO LA CONEXION!, código " +  connCode);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "NO SE PUDO REALIZAR LA CONEXION!");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } 
    return is;
}
```

Realizados estos cambios puedes ejecutar tu Asynctask y obtener los datos sin problema:

```
String url = "https://www.turismoasturias.es/open-data/catalogo-de-datos?p_p_id=opendata_WAR_importportlet&p_p_lifecycle=2&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=exportJson&p_p_cacheability=cacheLevelPage&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_opendata_WAR_importportlet_structure=27548&_opendata_WAR_importportlet_robots=nofollow";
new DownloadJsonTask().execute(url);
```

#### Otra forma importante de optimizar descargas en dispositivos móviles es comprimir el archivo a descargar, a formato **.gzip**, por ejemplo el archivo que deseas descargar, al contener texto, si es comprimido reduce dramáticamente el tamaño! :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces realizamos un cambio en nuestro método para obtención de datos a partir de la Url :

```
private InputStream openHttpInputStream(String myUrl) {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        conn.connect();
        int resCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.i(TAG, "resCode : " + resCode);
        if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Se realizo la conexión!");
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            if(myUrl.indexOf(".gz")>0){ //detectamos si el archivo esta compreso.
                is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
                Log.i(TAG, "El url esta compreso como .gzip!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "NO SE PUDO REALIZAR LA CONEXION! errorCode: " + resCode);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return is;
}
```

Ahora si revisamos el tiempo que tarda en descargar los datos en lugar de casí 20 segundos, ahora tarda menos de 1 segundo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38182/discussion-on-answer-by-elenasys-error-de-timeout-al-cargar-datos-url-android).

Comment: El problema es que no puedo entrar a un chat, por esa razón ahora no puedo ayudar al usuario... :(

Comment: Revisaré tu caso en unas horas o a más tardar el lunes, me pondré en contacto con Juan para ver qué se puede hacer al respecto.

Comment: Si me pueden ayudar sería excelente, gracias de antemano!.

Comment: Yo no tengo problema para acceder al chat

Answer (score 0):

Agrego una nueva respuesta ya que se edito la pregunta y no corresponde al problema original "Error de timeout al cargar datos url android", ahora el problema es :

> ExceptionIE :
>   org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: **Could
>   not   validate certificate signature.** 04-04 17:55:12.647
>   3641-3705/es.proyecto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:     AsyncTask

Este error puede deberse a diferentes causas pero aunque sea ridículo, puede deberse a que tu dispositivo/emulador esta configurado con la hora y fecha incorrecta.

Creo que este es el problema ya que primeramente no tuviste problema al leer el archivo pero si para procesarlo.

Comment: He probado a cambiar la fecha y hora y sigue sigo sin poder. Probé a descargarme el archivo directamente desde el dispositivo y me indica que la descarga falló.

Comment: probando sin ssl, me refiero http:// también falla?

Comment: SI, también falla

Comment: Hola @adamista,  recuerdo no tuve problema al cargar el .json, y tu tampoco cuando cargabas un .json mas pequeño, ahora también tendras el mismo problema con uno pequeño?

Comment: Si, ahora me realiza la conexión pero no lee todos los datos y ya probé a comprimirlos. Edité mi pregunta para incorporar el error que me muestra en el logCat

Comment: Acabo de ver que usas un emulador para probar, "3.2 HVGA slider (ADP1) API 10", yo uso preferentemente dispositivos físicos,  ¨Precisamente te iba a preguntar que usabas, he probado con 3 diferentes dispositivos la descarga del .json de tamaño mayor y no tengo problema, has tratado con uno fisíco?

Comment: No dispongo de un dispositivo físico con esa API. Me tendría que funcionar en el emulador.