# Hilos Android, AsyncTask o Runnable

Tags: android, webservice, hilos

Voy a empezar a picar código referente a hilos en java para que me realice una serie de peticiones web.

```
Stock stock = null;

    try {
        stock = YahooFinance.get("YHOO");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BigDecimal price = stock.getQuote().getPrice();
    BigDecimal change = stock.getQuote().getChangeInPercent();
    BigDecimal peg = stock.getStats().getPeg();
    BigDecimal dividend = stock.getDividend().getAnnualYieldPercent();

    stock.print();
```

Al añadir las lineas de código que hacen las peticiones me cascaba la aplicación cada vez que entraba en la activiad cuyo código tenia eso. Y leyendo por internet me decía que tenia que gestionarlo con hilos.

Indagando vi que había dos tipos de hilos AsyncTask y Runnable. ¿Cual debería emplear para un bucle infinito? Donde constantemente estará realizando las peticiones cuya única condición sera la de esperar un tiempo hasta que vuelva a hacer la petición, una especia de pausa me refiero.

Comment: Existen varias maneras para hacer hilos background en Android todo depende del enfoque, por ejemplo un runable yo lo veo más para cosas que se debe ejecutar cada cierto tiempo durante la activity en pantalla, un asynctask para un proceso de inicio a fin y que tiene que mostrar el proceso, un servicio para hacer correr en background y capturar su información con un broadcast desde una actividad en concreta para actualizar el ui.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte  me informaré algo mejor gracias !!

Comment: puedes echarle un ojo a esta pregunta y respuesta mía https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/30348/14088 en la que realizo un cron para hacer un envío de datos periódico cada x minutos a un servidor, igual te puede servir de ayuda o como orientación

Comment: @EduardoMéndez considera antes de agregar una respuesta buscar si existe algo similar en el sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38201/diferencia-entre-runnable-handler-thread/38210#38210

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41283/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-mandar-llamar-varias-veces-a-un-hilo-en-android

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6841/error-de-timeout-al-cargar-datos-url-android/6846#6846   SALUDOS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar cualquiera de las tres, pero yo te recomendaría el AsyncTask y te voy a explicar porqué:

Primero te diré que en Android, el hilo principal es el que maneja la interfaz de usuario, y el sistema nos impide realizar acciones que requieran red (peticiones a servidor y esas cosas) desde el hilo principal, es por eso que se debe usar Runnable, Thread o AsyncTask.

Creo que quizá lo que mejor te sirva en tu caso es un SyncAdapter o algo que realize las peticiones de forma periódica, utilizando alarmas y Services.
Desde un Service no hace falta usar Asynctask o Runnables para realizar peticiones.
Sobre SyncAdapters no puedo ayudarte mucho, se que existen , pero apenas los he tocado y son algo mas dificiles de configurar y a vece spueden bloquearse.

Si usas Runnable o Thread, cuando quisieras modificar algo de la pantalla al terminar cada peticion o algo por el estilo, tendrías que llamar al activity que se esta ejecutando y llamar el método "runOnUiThread"(por ejemplo, myActivity.runOnUIThread(Le pasas el objeto runnable o Thread para que lo ejecute en el hilo principal).

Pero si utilizas AsyncTask, te evitas ese runOnUiThread.
Te pongo un ejemplo:

Quiero hacer la peticion A al servidor
Creo AsyncTask
muestro un diálogo de cargando
La ejecuto
La asynctask hace la peticion y obtiene un resultado.
La asynctask termina y puedes actualizar la interfaz de usuario y lanzar una nueva asyncTask (puedes poner un thread sleep al principio de cada asynctask)

Te explico como va el AsyncTask:
en el método onPreExecute: tienes acceso a la interfaz de usuario, se suele usar para mostrar diálogos para indicar que se está cargando algo
en el método doOnBackground: Este método realmente se está ejecutando en otro hilo, asi que es donde se ponen las peticiones
en el método onPostExecute: tienes acceso a la interfaz de usuario y como parámetro recibe lo que el método "doOnBackground" devuelve como resultado.
en el método onProgressUpdate: también tienes acceso a la interfaz de usuario y se suele usar cuando quieres notificar al usuario el proceso de descarga o casos similares. Se le llama desde el doOnBackground llamando al método publishProgress.

Repito que cualquier clase te vale, pero ami personalmente me gusta más en asynctask porque tiene los diferentes métodos separados para poder acceder a la interfaz de usuario.

Un saludo!

Comment: Que bueno gracias por la explicación ahora comprendo mejor los conceptos. Tratare de determinar cuál me viene mejor pero en un principio me decanto por AsyncTask

Comment: También puedes compaginar un runnable que se ejecute cada N tiempo y el runnable execute el asynctask, para no tener que enrar en servicios de alarmas etc...

Comment: Yo he tenido problemas para lanzar un asynctask desde otro asynctask , asi que no se muy bien como se comportará android si desde un hiilo secundario lanzar otro hilo secundario

Comment: Bueno nunca lo he usado pero he visto varios ejemplos por allí, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207362/how-to-run-an-async-task-for-every-x-mins-in-android lo que debes controlar que si el asyntask esta en ejecución no lanzarlo de nuevo.

Comment: en el metodo onPostExecute puedes hacerlo,  pero no te guardes el objeto asynctask y le hagas execute otra vez porque a mi me ha fallado, crea un objeto Asynctask nuevo.